# angular2 How to get json id key?

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to get JSON data from the server. I succeed to make a request that returns the data, but I can't access the collection key. I printed the whole object, and the key exists, but I don't know how to get it.  I want to get the key value like `"-Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUSIgs"`, here is the console output and my code, any help, please ??

[Object printed in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERFL4.png) and [Here my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJmq.png)

Comment: add your code to the post and not as an image

Comment: Did you try `data["-Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUSIgs"]`?

Comment: i wanna  get this value "-Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUSIgs" not what inside data["-Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUSIgs"]

Comment: Please post your code and the json sample in your question, not as links to images. Your json is not an array or list of object, but instead a map or dictionary like object. Use Object.keys(data) to get an array of your key names and data[key] to then get the value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Sofiane Ben Khemis, please read this: [how-to-use-stack-overflow](https://blog.jondh.me.uk/2012/09/how-to-use-stack-overflow/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you  just have one key in your object you can use `Object.keys(row)[0]`

```js
let data = [
  {"Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUSIgs": {date: '', desc: ''}},
  {"Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUS123": {date: '', desc: ''}},
  {"Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUS456": {date: '', desc: ''}}
  ]
  
  
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   let row = data[i];    
   console.log(Object.keys(row)[0]);   
  }
```

Comment: this is it , thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use for.in to access the key values of the object like:

```
var test = {jfhajsk: 'sdgfdg', '-ksdakahcsak': 'asfdwf', 1: 34, 3: 'dsgfg'}
for(var i in test) {
    console.log(i);//Will print jfhajsk, -ksdakahcsak, 1 and 3
    console.log(test[i]);//Will print sdgfdg, asfdwf, 3 and dsgfg
}
```

If you want to simply print the value of the specified key, just do `console.log(variable_name['-Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUSIgs'])`

Comment: `loadAllPackages () {
    this.http
      .get('https://sofiane-5a3d8.firebaseio.com/forum.json')
      .map((res: any) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .subscribe (
        (data: any) => {
          this.packageData.next(data);
          console.log(data)
        },
        (err: any) => console.error("loadAllPackages: ERROR"),
        () => console.log("loadAllPackages: always")
      );
  }`

Comment: i cant do this in my case because i have to subscribe to get the data and eterate them

Comment: I'll simplify it for you. Without knowing what the key is or looks like, you can in no way retrieve it from this json. All rest would be quess work.

Comment: If the server is in your control as well, change the json to add the key like {key: "-Ki0NyOnNuPFbtkUSIgs": { data: "data"}} and access the key with data.key